# Using .rolling() to find dates when values satisfied condition within a certain window

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with several columns of weather obs, which are indexed with a date_time. I am trying to find all of the times when a the 'GSpd' column is over a threshold for three consecutive hours. I am using the following code, which appears to be working:

```
    df_roll = df['GSpd'].rolling(3)
    df3 = df_roll.apply(lambda x:x[0] if x[0] >= wind else np.nan).dropna()
```

However, I want to recombine df3 with the original df so I can analyze the other obs when the winds are above the threshold. I have also got that to work:

```
    df = pd.concat([df, df3], axis=1)
    df = df.dropna()
```

This data frame still has the original GSpd column. Is the index with the last row in the rolling window the one that is preserved? Just doing some QC to make sure I am analyzing this right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the index on the last row/observation in the window will be the index that "collects" the result for the window.

The documentation isn't clear on this but we can check quickly:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [i for i in range(5)]})
print(df.rolling(3).max())
```